# Backbone.Marionette overriding methods

Tags: coffeescript, marionette

In 0.9.3, the region manager has changed with the following entry in the changelog:

> - **BREAKING** Changed the implementation of `Region` to allow easier
>     overriding of how the new view is added to the DOM

What is the best way of overriding the open method?

Currently I am doing the following which does work but I am curious to know what the recommended way is:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Marionette.Region.prototype, {
  open: (view) ->
    @$el.after(view.el)
})
```

This change has also broken some code for me because in some cases I was calling show like this:

```
region.show(documentsView, 'after')
```

And in others I was calling it like this:

```
region.show unitsView
```

How can I override open to take both these instances into account or do I need to override show?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Marionette.Region.prototype, {
        show: (view, appendMethod) ->
            @ensureEl()
            @close()

            view.render()

            @open(view, appendMethod)
            @currentView = view

        open: (view, appendMethod) ->
            appendMethod = appendMethod || "html"
            @$el[appendMethod](view.el)
    })
```